# How to adjust vertical spacing in a matrix with an horizontal line?

Tags: amsmath, matrices, line-spacing, vertical-spacing

I'm having trouble  in balancing the vertical spacings in matrices which have a horizontal separation line, like in the following MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{gray1}{RGB}{100,100,100}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{2ex}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\abovedisplayskip}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{\belowdisplayskip}
\setlength{\jot}{3ex}

\begin{equation}
    M =\!
    \arrayrulecolor{gray1}
    \left[ \begin{array}{c|ccc}
        A & 0 & 0 & E \\[2.1pt]  % To be adjusted
        \hline \\[-12.5pt]  % To be adjusted
        0 & B & 0 & 0 \\[1em]
        0 & 0 & C & 0 \\[1em]
        E & 0 & 0 & D
    \end{array} \right]\!.
\end{equation}
Bla bla blabla:
\begin{equation}
    M =\!
    \arrayrulecolor{gray1}
    \left[ \begin{array}{c|ccc}
        A & 0 & 0 & E \\[1ex]  % To be adjusted
        \hline \\  % To be adjusted
        0 & B & 0 & 0 \\[1em]
        0 & 0 & C & 0 \\[1em]
        E & 0 & 0 & D
    \end{array} \right]\!.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Preview :

[image]

In the first matrix, I adjusted the vertical spacing by eye only, using `\\[2.1pt]` and `\\[-12.5pt]`, which is clearly a  hack (and yet, the result isn't right).

I need the elements in the first and second lines to have the same vertical spacing as all the other lines below them (`\\[1em]`).  How can I get that, instead of adjusting the vertical spacing by eye?

Comment: I think this is best handled manually, although it's a pain.  I suggest obtaining a good point scale; the `pointruler` tool is available on CTAN (easy to look up by that name).  Print it out, preferably on acetate or some other stable transparent medium and measure away.  Also, `em` isn't the best font-specific unit to use for vertical dimensions, since it's defined to be horizontal.  `ex` (the x-height) is much better, although you'll have to adjust your mental concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it like you want?

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{gray1}{RGB}{100,100,100}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{2ex}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\abovedisplayskip}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{\belowdisplayskip}
\setlength{\jot}{3ex}

\begin{equation}
    M =\!
    \arrayrulecolor{gray1}
    \left[ \begin{array}{c|ccc}
        A & 0 & 0 & E \\[2.1pt] % To be adjusted
        \hline \\[-12.5pt] % To be adjusted
        0 & B & 0 & 0 \\[1em]
        0 & 0 & C & 0 \\[1em]
        E & 0 & 0 & D
    \end{array} \right]\!.
\end{equation}
Bla bla blabla:
\begin{equation}
    M =\!
    \arrayrulecolor{gray1}
    \left[ \begin{array}{c|ccc}
        A & 0 & 0 & E \\[0.5ex] % To be adjusted
        \hline \\[\dimexpr 1em-0.5ex-\arrayrulewidth-\jot] % To be adjusted
        0 & B & 0 & 0 \\[1em]
        0 & 0 & C & 0 \\[1em]
        E & 0 & 0 & D
    \end{array} \right]\!.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: To have the horizontal libe vericalyy centred w.r.t. the rows above and below, use this code:

```
\begin{equation}
    M =\!
    \arrayrulecolor{gray1}
    \left[ \begin{array}{c|ccc}
        A & 0 & 0 & E \\[\dimexpr 0.5em-0.5\arrayrulewidth] % To be adjusted
        \hline \\[\dimexpr 0.5em-0.5\arrayrulewidth-\jot] % To be adjusted
        0 & B & 0 & 0 \\[1em]
        0 & 0 & C & 0 \\[1em]
        E & 0 & 0 & D
    \end{array} \right]\!.
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks very good.  Is it possible to put the horizontal line in the middle of that vertical space?  It's currently a bit too high, relative to the elements A and B.

Comment: @Cham: Please see my edit for a solution.

Comment: Marvelous!  Is there a way to make this a macro declared in the preamble, so I could just type a small command on each sides of the \\ ?  If so, what would you suggest?

Comment: Define macro in the preamble `\newcommand{\Chline}[1]{\\[\dimexpr0.5#1]\hline \\[\dimexpr0.5#1-\jot-\arrayrulewidth]}` ande use `\Chline{some length}` in the place of  `\\ \hline`.