# Horizontal line in matrix not well balanced

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices, line, vertical-spacing

I'm having troubles in drawing an horizontal line inside a matrix.  As from this MWE code, the line isn't well balanced relative to the equal sign (it should be aligned, vertically), and there's a pesky white hole below the middle:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

%\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1em}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\abovedisplayskip}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{\belowdisplayskip}
\setlength{\jot}{3ex}

    \begin{equation}
        R = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
        \tensor{R}{_{0101}} & \tensor{R}{_{0102}} & \tensor{R}{_{0103}} & \tensor{R}{_{0123}} & \tensor{R}{_{0131}} & \tensor{R}{_{0112}} \\[2ex]
        \tensor{R}{_{0102}} & \tensor{R}{_{0202}} & \tensor{R}{_{0203}} & \tensor{R}{_{0223}} & \tensor{R}{_{0231}} & \tensor{R}{_{0212}} \\[2ex]
        \tensor{R}{_{0103}} & \tensor{R}{_{0203}} & \tensor{R}{_{0303}} & \tensor{R}{_{0323}} & \tensor{R}{_{0331}} & \tensor{R}{_{0312}}
        \\[\dimexpr 1ex+2\arrayrulewidth] \hline \\[\dimexpr 1ex-2\arrayrulewidth-\jot]
        \tensor{R}{_{0123}} & \tensor{R}{_{0223}} & \tensor{R}{_{0323}} & \tensor{R}{_{2323}} & \tensor{R}{_{2331}} & \tensor{R}{_{2312}} \\[2ex]
        \tensor{R}{_{0131}} & \tensor{R}{_{0231}} & \tensor{R}{_{0331}} & \tensor{R}{_{2331}} & \tensor{R}{_{3131}} & \tensor{R}{_{3112}} \\[2ex]
        \tensor{R}{_{0112}} & \tensor{R}{_{0212}} & \tensor{R}{_{0312}} & \tensor{R}{_{2312}} & \tensor{R}{_{3112}} & \tensor{R}{_{1212}}
    \end{array} \right]\!.
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

So how can I modify that code so the horizontal line is well balanced vertically in the matrix, without that whiloe hole under it?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240859/dividing-line-in-a-matrix

Comment: @jsbibra, none of the solutions from your link give a proper result.  There are still white gaps, and the line isn't well balanced.

Comment: My line is drawn from an answer found there: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540022/how-to-adjust-vertical-spacing-in-a-matrix-with-an-horizontal-line?noredirect=1#comment1364288_540022

Comment: Why do you use superfluous `tensor` package for the subscripts?

Answer (score 1):

from --https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240859/dividing-line-in-a-matrix

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tensor}
\begin{document}
    \[
    M = 
    \left( \begin{array}{c|c}
    A & B \\
    \midrule
    C & D \\
    \end{array}\right)
    \]
    \[
     R = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
        \tensor{R}{_{0101}} & \tensor{R}{_{0102}} & \tensor{R}{_{0103}} & \tensor{R}{_{0123}} & \tensor{R}{_{0131}} & \tensor{R}{_{0112}} \\[2ex]
        \tensor{R}{_{0102}} & \tensor{R}{_{0202}} & \tensor{R}{_{0203}} & \tensor{R}{_{0223}} & \tensor{R}{_{0231}} & \tensor{R}{_{0212}} \\[2ex]
        \tensor{R}{_{0103}} & \tensor{R}{_{0203}} & \tensor{R}{_{0303}} & \tensor{R}{_{0323}} & \tensor{R}{_{0331}} & \tensor{R}{_{0312}}
        \\ \midrule
        \tensor{R}{_{0123}} & \tensor{R}{_{0223}} & \tensor{R}{_{0323}} & \tensor{R}{_{2323}} & \tensor{R}{_{2331}} & \tensor{R}{_{2312}} \\[2ex]
        \tensor{R}{_{0131}} & \tensor{R}{_{0231}} & \tensor{R}{_{0331}} & \tensor{R}{_{2331}} & \tensor{R}{_{3131}} & \tensor{R}{_{3112}} \\[2ex]
        \tensor{R}{_{0112}} & \tensor{R}{_{0212}} & \tensor{R}{_{0312}} & \tensor{R}{_{2312}} & \tensor{R}{_{3112}} & \tensor{R}{_{1212}}
    \end{array} \right]\!.
    \]
\end{document}
```

**edit -- with intersection no hole aligned to = sign**

```
 R = \left[ \begin{array}{@{\,}ccc|ccc@{\,}}
        \tensor{R}{_{0101}} & \tensor{R}{_{0102}} & \tensor{R}{_{0103}} & \tensor{R}{_{0123}} & \tensor{R}{_{0131}} & \tensor{R}{_{0112}} \\
        \tensor{R}{_{0102}} & \tensor{R}{_{0202}} & \tensor{R}{_{0203}} & \tensor{R}{_{0223}} & \tensor{R}{_{0231}} & \tensor{R}{_{0212}} \\
        \tensor{R}{_{0103}} & \tensor{R}{_{0203}} & \tensor{R}{_{0303}} & \tensor{R}{_{0323}} & \tensor{R}{_{0331}} & \tensor{R}{_{0312}}
        \\ \hline
        \tensor{R}{_{0123}} & \tensor{R}{_{0223}} & \tensor{R}{_{0323}} & \tensor{R}{_{2323}} & \tensor{R}{_{2331}} & \tensor{R}{_{2312}} \\
        \tensor{R}{_{0131}} & \tensor{R}{_{0231}} & \tensor{R}{_{0331}} & \tensor{R}{_{2331}} & \tensor{R}{_{3131}} & \tensor{R}{_{3112}} \\
        \tensor{R}{_{0112}} & \tensor{R}{_{0212}} & \tensor{R}{_{0312}} & \tensor{R}{_{2312}} & \tensor{R}{_{3112}} & \tensor{R}{_{1212}}
    \end{array} \right]\!.
```

[image]

Comment: That line still have gaps in the middle.  And the elements don't have a proper spacing around the line, compared with other elements in the matrix.

Comment: See the solution from that answer (which strangely doesn't work well here): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540022/how-to-adjust-vertical-spacing-in-a-matrix-with-an-horizontal-line?noredirect=1#comment1364288_540022

Comment: Addendum: If you need a bit of extra vertical separation between the rows, you could load the array package and issue the instruction \setlength\extrarowheight{1pt} in the preamble. This may be particularly useful if the submatrices have diacritics (such as \bar{...}) that would otherwise come too close to the \hline

Comment: By the way: Sat Sri Akaal !

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246844/matrix-hline-is-cut-by-cmidrule

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of `nicematrix` (v 5.1 of 2020-07-31), the vertical rules specified by `|` in the preamble of `{NiceArray}` (similar to `{array}` of `array`) are never broken (because they are drawn in fact by PGF/Tikz).

So, you can write directly without broken vertical rule:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\abovedisplayskip}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{\belowdisplayskip}
\setlength{\jot}{3ex}

\begin{equation}
    R = \left[ \begin{NiceArray}{ccc|ccc}
    \tensor{R}{_{0101}} & \tensor{R}{_{0102}} & \tensor{R}{_{0103}} & \tensor{R}{_{0123}} & \tensor{R}{_{0131}} & \tensor{R}{_{0112}} \\[2ex]
    \tensor{R}{_{0102}} & \tensor{R}{_{0202}} & \tensor{R}{_{0203}} & \tensor{R}{_{0223}} & \tensor{R}{_{0231}} & \tensor{R}{_{0212}} \\[2ex]
    \tensor{R}{_{0103}} & \tensor{R}{_{0203}} & \tensor{R}{_{0303}} & \tensor{R}{_{0323}} & \tensor{R}{_{0331}} & \tensor{R}{_{0312}}
    \\[\dimexpr 1ex+2\arrayrulewidth] \hline \\[\dimexpr 1ex-2\arrayrulewidth-\jot]
    \tensor{R}{_{0123}} & \tensor{R}{_{0223}} & \tensor{R}{_{0323}} & \tensor{R}{_{2323}} & \tensor{R}{_{2331}} & \tensor{R}{_{2312}} \\[2ex]
    \tensor{R}{_{0131}} & \tensor{R}{_{0231}} & \tensor{R}{_{0331}} & \tensor{R}{_{2331}} & \tensor{R}{_{3131}} & \tensor{R}{_{3112}} \\[2ex]
    \tensor{R}{_{0112}} & \tensor{R}{_{0212}} & \tensor{R}{_{0312}} & \tensor{R}{_{2312}} & \tensor{R}{_{3112}} & \tensor{R}{_{1212}}
\end{NiceArray} \right]\!.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]